# Android: How to give support for material design (api 21) features on previous api levels?

Tags: android, material-design

if we want to provide material design's Date/Time picker or any other feature  support for previous api levels in our Android project, how it can be achieved? I read it some where that we need to port the source out of api 21, but i have no idea how to port source and the source to look.
Google Calender app is using the same kind of Time and Date pickers.
[link](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/05/colordatetime.png)   im using the same pickers in Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case you might want to take a look at [zenyagami/DateTimepicker](https://github.com/zenyagami/DateTimepicker) library.

EDIT:

Check out Date Pickers section on [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/free) for more libraries for your use case.

Comment: i don't want to go for a third party library

Comment: Care to share the reason? They're open source, free, *do exactly what you need without you having to write it yourself*, some of them may even be lifted from KitKat/Lollipop source code...

Comment: because i was hoping to learn a way to use Material design features, what if in future i have to use any other feature then i would already have a lead    on how to achieve it.

Comment: So you want to *use* it. Most of the time these libraries use the same API as their native counterparts (if it's a backport of some sort) or a "fluent" API (used e.g. in `AlertDialog.Builder`). Well, even if a library was developed by Google Almighty you'd still have to learn how to *use* it and nobody will guarantee it's not going to change. And something new will always come up. So it boils down to this: Either you want to use it so you try to find a library which suits your use case best OR you want to make such library yourself according to the specs.

Comment: yes, i just want to use them that's it, it doesn't matter if it change in the future

Comment: Good, then you need to look among third-party libraries as well. As I said, Google itself is not implementing many features described in the Material Design spec.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the [Navasmdc MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) for buttons.
You can use the setSupportActionBar() to use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) on lower API versions.
As Eugen points out, there i [zenyagami/DateTimepicker](https://github.com/zenyagami/DateTimepicker) for Date pickers.
There is [fengdai/AlertDialogPro](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro) for dialogs.

Comment: AFAIK there's no Date/Time picker in this library.

Comment: date and time pickers [link](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/pickers.html)

Comment: The link you posted - those are the new design specs. Keyword: specs. Except for the Material theme nothing really is implemented by Google in the support library. But there are third-party libraries which implement some of it (e.g. SnackBar).

Comment: i didn't know that before